Fastest way to calculate the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue for a 3*3 positive-definite matrix
As stated in the title: I have a 3 by 3 positive-definite matrix $M$. What I need is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue, since I am calculating the solution to maximize the value of $w^T M w$, with $w\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 1}$ and $\Vert w\Vert_2 = 1$.
This calculation is to be put into a shader code, so efficiency is the top priority and I want to avoid any useless computation (meaning the result is not going to be used anyway, but it will consume some registers or GPU cycles) if possible. So is there any method to only compute the very vector I want without calculating other stuffs (for example, SVD computes almost everything related to eigenvector)? Or if not, what is the suggested method I should take?

You can have a look at https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/RobustEigenSymmetric3x3.pdf I don't claim it's the fastest though. The most naive approach would be a power iteration instead.

Also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33410/fast-and-accurate-eigenvalue-computation-for-3x3-posdef-matrices
